# Cypress cy.wrap() not storing value from cy.invoke()

Tags: cypress, alias

I was hoping someone would be able to solve probably a fairly basic problem I was having. In the console I can see the username being stored but during my wrap command that value is not being picked up. Any ideas what I need to change so that my Cy.wrap stores the value picked up by my Cy.invoke?

Goal was Cy.Wrap to pick up username that could then be retried to login with the later step by entering the login credentials.

```js
cy.get('#memberID').invoke('val').as('generatedUsername').then(cy.log)
cy.wrap('userId').as('generatedUsername').then(cy.log)
cy.get('[class="positive-complete qualifiedFunctionalityCommand positive"]').eq(3).click(),
cy.contains('Logout').click()
cy.get('@generatedUsername').then( memberID => {
  cy.get('#j_username').type(memberID)
})
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just add brackets to the data. See [JSON Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that the logout process must be resetting the Cypress testing frame (the AUT).

Maybe it is causing the alias to be wiped from memory. I would not expect it to be so, but you can double check by doing this:

```js
cy.get('#memberID').invoke('val').as('generatedUsername').then(cy.log)  // logs ok

cy.contains('Logout').click()
cy.get(some-selector-that-indicates-page-is-logged-out)

cy.get('@generatedUsername').then(cy.log)              // does this log undefined?
```

If so, one remedy to try (may also not work for same reason)

```js
cy.get('#memberID').invoke('val')
  .then(generatedUsername => Cypress.env('generatedUsername', generatedUsername ))  

cy.contains('Logout').click()
cy.get(some-selector-that-indicates-page-is-logged-out)

cy.wrap(Cypress.env('generatedUsername')).then(cy.log)    / does this log ok?
```

Still no luck? Change to saving in a file

```js
cy.get('#memberID').invoke('val')
  .then(generatedUsername => {
    const jsonObject = { generatedUsername }
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/generatedUsername.json', jsonObject)
  })  

cy.contains('Logout').click()
cy.get(some-selector-that-indicates-page-is-logged-out)

cy.fixture('generatedUsername.json').then(cy.log)    / does this log ok?
```

---

I also noticed you have some commas at end of line - they have some subtle meaning in Javascript that may be causing your problem.

Try being rigorous in correctly formatting your code, you may be introducing errors just because of sloppy syntax.

Comment: So I tried all 3 options and it appears the 3rd one works, I just need to figure out how to tweak what is being written to the JSON. Here is what I'm seeing (see screenshot).

Comment: Ok so what I've realized is that when I logout and try to pick up generatedUsername its not wrapped so therefore cypress reads it as undefined. My issue is that I'm having a hard time figure out how to wrap the variable so that cypress can later grab the generateduser name and use cy.type to enter this information. 
Would anyone be able to help show me how this should be done based on the code provided?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of fumbling around I believe I found the solution, logging credentials to a read file was not needed.

```js
  cy.get('#memberID').then(($memberId) => {
    cy.wrap($memberId).invoke('val').as('generatedUsername').then(cy.log)
  })
```

Thanks all for the feedback.

Comment: Ok, so how does this do anything different?

Answer (score -1):

You're setting the value of the `@generatedUsername` alias twice - once from the invoked value from `#memberId`, and then again as just the string `'userId'`.

In your test runner, if you click on the first time that `generatedUsername` is tagged, you'll see the value is the yielded value from `#memberId`. The following should work as you'd expect.

```js
cy.get('#memberID').invoke('val').as('generatedUsername');
cy.get('[class="positive-complete qualifiedFunctionalityCommand positive"]').eq(3).click();
cy.contains('Logout').click();
cy.get('@generatedUsername').then((memberID) => {
    cy.get('#j_username').type(memberID)
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback agoff. I tried the code above and got the following error:cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefined

This was the reason I was using the Cy.wrap its just for some reason its not grabbing the value from the invoke above